# How to fix image width and height for a string can contain multiple images

Tags: php

I have a multi templates of contents (strings) stored in a database, some of these strings have images with a defined height and width, some without these attrebutes, and some with invalid attributes values.

I need to pass all these strings over a function that can fix this issue, and set a real width and height attributes based on the real image size, it's easy, i have trubbles doing this and save the image location inside the string without changing it.

example: 
before fix:

```
some text <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt"some alt" /> another some text <img src="/images/image2.jpg" alt="another some alt" width="519" /> agian some text <img src="/images/i.jpg" width="519" height="450" alt="text alt" /> <p> <img src="/images/image2.jpg" alt="another some alt" height="400" /></p>
```

after fix, all images have width and height

```
some text <img src="/images/image.jpg"  width="530" height"600" alt"some alt" /> another some text <img src="/images/image2.jpg" alt="another some alt" width="519" height"400" /> agian some text <img src="/images/i.jpg" width="519" height="450" alt="text alt" /> <p> <img src="/images/image2.jpg" alt="another some alt" width="800" height="400" /></p>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are all the images meant to be the same size? If so then use a CSS class to set their dimensions as this will override the width and height attributes.

Comment: No, that's the problem.

Comment: @NimerSulieman you’ll need to parse the string for the image paths (try https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser) then use something like http://image.intervention.io/ to get the images sizes. You might be able to repalce the height and width with the HTML parser or set them with a style attribute rather than trying to update them on the img tag.

Comment: Thanks Richard for advise